# Django TEMPLATEDOESNOTEXIST; multiple settings files

Tags: django, docker, settings

I am trying to implement multiple settings files in Django using Docker.

I have a settings package as follows:

```
> settings
   __init__.py
   base.py
   testing.py
```

I run docker-compose up with the following command in the .yml:

```
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 --settings=mysite.settings.testing
```

The manage.py file is updated as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings.testing")
```

My `testing.py` simply contains the following as of right now:

```
from .base import *
```

I run `dc-up` command and the Django container starts without issue. However, when I try to load a webpage, it returns a TEMPLATEDOESNOTEXIST error.

I have tried replacing `.testing` with `.base` and same error.

I know it is settings package related because if I switch back to a single `settings.py` file, there is no error.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you get to solve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Negative. Let me know if you do.

Comment: Really? so what are you doing in production/development environments?

Comment: Do you happen to use Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

Approximately an issue caused by incorrect template path settings(in my case templates settings looks like):

```
     BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

I fixed it as follows:

```
     BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```